# Finding sequence in data

Tags: awk

I to use awk to find the sequence of pattern in a DNA data but I cannot figure out how to do it. I have a text file "test.tx" which contains a lot of data and I want to be able to match any sequence that starts with ATG and ends with TAA, TGA or TAG and prints them.

for instance, if my text file has data that look like below. I want to find and match all the existing sequence and output as below.

```html
AGACGCCGGAAGGTCCGAACATCGGCCTTATTTCGTCGCTCTCTTGCTTTGCTCGAATAAACGAGTTTGGCTTTATCGAATCTCCGTACCGTAAGGTCGAAAACGGCCGGGTCATTGAGTACGTGAAAGTACAAAATGG
GTCCGCGAATTTTTCGGTTCGTCTCAGCTTTCGCAGTTTATGGATCAGACGAACCCGCTCTCTGAAATTACTCATAAACGCAGGCTCTCGGCGCTCGGGCCCGGCGGACTCTCGCGGGAGCGTGCAGGTTTCGAAGTTC
GGATGATATCGACCATCTCGGCAATCGACGCGTTCGGGCCGTAGGCGAACTGCTCGAAAATCAATTCCGAATCGGGCTTGAGCGAATGGAGCGGGCCATCAAGGAAAAAATGTCTATCCAGCAGGATATGCAAACGACG
AAAGTATGTTTTTCGATCCGCGCCGATTCGACCTCTCAAGAGTCGGAAGGCTTAAATTCAATATCAAAATGGGACGCCCCGAGCGCGACCGTATAGACGATCCGCTGCTTGCGCCGATGGATTTCATCGACGTTGTGAA
ATGAGACCGGGCGATCCGCCGACTGTGCCAACCGCCTACCGGCTTCTGG
```

```html
Print out matches:
ATGATATCGACCATCTCGGCAATCGACGCGTTCGGGCCGTAG
ATGATATCGACCATCTCGGCAATCGACGCGTTCGGGCCGTAG
ATGTTTTTCGATCCGCGCCGATTCGACCTCTCAAGAGTCGGAAGGCTTAA
```

I try something like this, but it only display the rows that starts with ATG. it doesn't actually fix my problem

```html
awk '/^AGT/{print $0}' test.txt
```

Comment: Try: `grep -Eo 'ATG.*(TAA|TGA|TAG)' test.txt`

Comment: Are the target sequences always contained within a line or can they span lines? Can multiple sequences occur on a line? Do the strings ATG, TAA, TGA, or TAG only appear once on a line at the start/end of a sequence or can they appear multiple times? If they can appear multiple times does the sequence go between the closest pair of terminators or the furthest apart or something else?

Comment: shouldn't span line, yes multiple sequences can occur within a line. They can appear multiple times.  yes, they can go between the closest pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/ATG.*TAA|ATG.*TGA|ATG.*TAG/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

Comment: `/ATG.*TAA|ATG.*TGA|ATG.*TAG/` = `/ATG.*T(AA|GA|AG)/`

Comment: Thanks, I try that but is missing some sequence

Answer (score 2):

assuming the records are not spanning multiple lines

```
$ grep -oP 'ATG.*?T(AA|AG|GA)' file

ATGGATCAGACGAACCCGCTCTCTGA
ATGATATCGACCATCTCGGCAATCGACGCGTTCGGGCCGTAG
ATGTTTTTCGATCCGCGCCGATTCGACCTCTCAAGAGTCGGAAGGCTTAA
ATGGGACGCCCCGAGCGCGACCGTATAG
ATGGATTTCATCGACGTTGTGA
```

non-greedy match, requires `-P` switch (to find the first match, not the longest).

Comment: @user11766958 It's not trivial to make `awk` matches non-greedy.